# Solution of a linear matrix differential equation

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, matrix-equations

Consider a linear matrix differential equation of the form

$$\frac{\mathrm{d} C}{\mathrm{d} t} = A C + C A^{\mathrm{T}}$$

where $C$ is a symmetric $n \times n$ matrix and $A$ is a $n \times n$ matrix. Find $C(t)$.

Is there a formal solution for the above equation? This is in principle linear equation if we treat the matrix $C$ and $A$ as a $n^2$ vector. However, it does not seem to be practical way to solve the problem.

This kind of differential equations for matrices is quite new to me.
Besides the formal solution let me know some books considering similar topic. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve the differential equation as follows: write
$$\frac{dC}{dt} = AC+CA^T = \left(A\otimes1+1\otimes A^T\right)C$$
This gives us the solution
$$C(t)=\exp\left(t\left(A\otimes1+1\otimes A^T\right)\right)C(0)$$
Notice that this is basically solving by looking at $A$ as a $n^2$-vector, as you said in the question. The nice thing with this formulation is that you notice at once that $A\otimes1$ and $1\otimes A^T$ commute, and thus we have
$$\exp\left(t\left(A\otimes1+1\otimes A^T\right)\right) = \exp\left(t\left(A\otimes1\right)\right)\exp\left(t\left(1\otimes A^T\right)\right)=$$
$$=\left(\exp(tA)\otimes1\right)\left(1\otimes \exp\left(tA^T\right)\right)$$
So
$$C(t) = \exp(tA)C(0)\exp\left(tA\right)^T$$
which you can easily check to be correct.

Comment: In the first equation, what is the dimension of identity matrix?

Comment: @Sungmin It must be $n\times n$ for everything to make sense.

Comment: There seems to be an error somewhere here, the dimensions don't match in several matrices being claim as equal. Assuming by $\otimes$ you mean the kronecker product, $(A \otimes I)C$ has a larger dimension than AC for example. As square matrices, $Dim(A \otimes I)=Dim(A)Dim(I) = n^2$ but $Dim(AC)=n$.