# Solving a certain matrix differential equation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, symmetric-matrices

I am trying to solve the following differential equation. All the matrices here are on $\mathbb{R}$.

Let $\sigma$ be a time $t$ dependent $2n \times 2n$ Hermitian matrix. I want to solve the following equation,
\begin{equation}
\frac{\mathrm{d}\sigma}{\mathrm{d}t}=A\sigma+\sigma A^T +D,
\end{equation}
where $A$ is any  $2n \times 2n$ matrix and $D$ is a positive semi-definite $2n \times 2n$ matrix given to us i.e. independent of $t$. $A^T$ denotes transpose of $A$.

How to get the conditions for existance/stability of solution(s)? Furthermore is it possible to get a general formula of the solution of the above equation?

In fact I want to consider solutions which are positive definite. However I did not work in ODE earlier, and not getting any clue of how to proceed. The problem is that though the right hand side is a Hermitain matrix, I don't know how the spectral decomposition will look like. Advanced thanks for any clue, comment, suggessions, references.

Comment: Maybe this post is a good start? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/578238/solution-of-a-linear-matrix-differential-equation?rq=1

Comment: @maxmilgram I am not too sure. The first step itself is somewhat strange. If we take $1$ as identity matrix of dimension $n$, then the dimensions do not match. On the other hand, if $1=[[1]]$ as a $1\times 1$ matrix, then I am not sure how $1 \otimes A^t C = CA^t$. Any idea?

Comment: did you find my answer helpful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So startting from [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/578238/solution-of-a-linear-matrix-differential-equation?rq=1) that deals with the homogeneous case, we take variation of constants to handle with $D$: (the verification of the formula will also be part of the calculation).

$$
\sigma=e^{tA}C(t)(e^{tA})^T\\
\Rightarrow \sigma'=Ae^{tA}C(t)(e^{tA})^T+e^{tA}C'(t)(e^{tA})^T+e^{tA}C(t)(e^{tA}A)^T
$$

here we have used basic properties of the matrix exponential and the matrix product rule, see e.g. formulas (33), (39) and (476) in the [matrix cookbook](https://courses.csail.mit.edu/6.867/wiki/images/7/77/Matrix_cookbook.pdf). Using the ODE we see that

$$
 \sigma'=\underbrace{Ae^{tA}C(t)(e^{tA})^T}_{=A\sigma}+e^{tA}C'(t)(e^{tA})^T+\underbrace{e^{tA}C(t)(e^{tA}A)^T}_{=\sigma A^T}\stackrel{!}{=}A\sigma+\sigma A^T +D\\
\Leftrightarrow e^{tA}C'(t)(e^{tA})^T=D\\\
\Leftrightarrow C'(t)= e^{-tA}D(e^{-tA})^T\\
\Leftrightarrow C=\int_0^t e^{-sA}D(e^{-sA})^Tds+C_0
$$

This gives
$$
\sigma=e^{tA}\left(\int_0^t e^{-sA}D(e^{-sA})^Tds\right)(e^{tA})^T+e^{tA}\sigma_0(e^{tA})^T
$$

as the full solution of the matrix ODE.